# Specify array length to call

Tags: java, arrays, listener

I'll explain my problem with an example:

```
 buttons[0][0].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
```

In the code above I'm adding a listener to my button in the upper left corner. Now I was wondering if there's an option, so I can call the entire line, something like `[0][0-3]`, so I can add the same action listener for all 4 of them (I know `0-3` will not work since it says that `-3` isn't specified in the array).

I know I can do this by adding a listener to the buttons one by one, but I have to make an `if` statement that when all the buttons have been pressed for example, it returns something.

Comment: It's not clear what the part about "all the buttons have been pressed" has to do with the rest... it's hard to answer usefully without that bit being explained.

Comment: Well the last part doesn't have anything to do with the main questions, so it isn't really that important i think. I was wondering if I can call an entire line in my array (in my case somethign like [0] [from 0 to 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in one call, the easiest way is to iterate over them:

```
ActionListener toAddToThoseButtons = new ActionListener() { /*...*/ };

for (int i=0; buttons[0].length; i++) {
    buttons[0][i].addActionListener(toAddToThoseButtons);
}
```

Comment: @Glenndisimo I see you're new to the site; we say thank you by upvoting and accepting answers (the green checkmark below the voting arrows on the left).  Thanks!

Comment: I can't seem to upvote since it requires 15 reputation (which I haven't got), thanks for the info!